# How can I use my 12' MB 2015 with AC power only? (No battery)

Tags: mac

My 12 inch MacBook from 2015's display broke and only works while connected to an external display.

I don't want to spend the $800 on a replacement display so I was hoping to use it as a full time server, almost like a Mac mini. I don't want to risk the battery though.

Can / should I, remove the battery somehow? And if so how? Do I even need to worry about this? I know lithium batteries can be unstable if you abuse them that way. I've also had to replace one on another mbp because I abused it too.

What do you guys think?

Comment: I don't see the need to take out the battery. If it was not damaged, it makes no sense to remove it. Yet, if you really want to, I think (I did it at least with a MacBook Air) you should be able to just take it out and run the MacBook from AC, but you will lose a considerable amount of performance.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving your MacBook plugged in is not "abuse". Apple's laptops contain power management that prevents any problems. Even while plugged in, you may see the battery % indicator change from between 93% to 100%.

https://support.apple.com/en-me/HT204054#notfull

> **My battery won't charge to 100%**
>
> > Occasionally, the battery might not show a full charge (100%) in
> >     macOS, even after the power adapter has been connected for an extended
> >     period of time. The battery might appear to stop charging between 93
> >     percent and 99 percent. This behavior is normal and will help to
> >     prolong the overall life of the battery.